# SQLite scripting with objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, database, ipad, sqlite

I have two .sqlite files. One for full version and one for Lite version.
I am choosing one .sqlite file for one condition with this code:

```
if (FULLVERSION) {
self.databaseName = @"Alpha.sqlite";
}
else {
self.databaseName = @"AlphaLite.sqlite";
}
```

Now when I query I want to use this self.databaseName in that. I am doing like this now:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) Alpha {
    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Alpha";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

    return alpha;   
}
```

In "SELECT * FROM Alpha" line, in place of Alpha I want to use self.databaseName, which will have database name according to the condition.

How to do this?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to select database or table?, in first line you have stated you have two different databases, and later in "select" statement you want to pass database name?, in select query you can pass <tablename> or <dbname>.<tableName>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Stringwithformat , then get utf8string

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@",self.databaseName];
const char *sqlStatement = [sql UTF8String];
```

Answer (score 1):

In `SELECT` statement, replace `const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Alpha";` with following two lines:

```
NSString *sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@", self.databaseName];
const char *sqlStatement = [sqlString UTF8String];
```

OR

Replace `const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Alpha";` with

```
const char *sqlStatement;
if (FULLVERSION) {
    sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Alpha";
} else {
    sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM AlphaLite";
}
```

Comment: const char *sqlStatement is declared inside if block ... be aware of it